# Implementing commas and decimals in autonumeric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which I am trying to get working with autonumeric.js. One of the errors I am getting is that `number is not supported by autoNumeric`. When I change the `input type` to `text` all inputs automatically auto fill to whatever number I am keying in. I am basically trying to start with adding commas and decimals, before i get into currency. I am a little confused as to where to go from here. This is my HTML

```
    <form id="form1">
       <h3>Lifetime Value Calculator</h3>
       <input value=""  type="number"  class='num1'/> 
       <input value=""  type="number" class='num2'/>           
       <input value=""  type="number" class='num3'/>
       <input value=""  type="number" class='num4'/>
   </form>
```

This is my script

```
 var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric('.num1, .num2, .num3, .num4', AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().numericPos.dotDecimalCharCommaSeparator);

$('.num1, .num2, .num3, .num4').on('keyup', function() {
    $('.num1, .num2, .num3, .num4').val(autoNumericInstance.getNumericString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress. I was able to get commas and decimals for my first input field, but only commas and NO decimals for my last input field, using this script

`

```
$('.num1, .num4').each(function() {
var autoNumericInstance = new AutoNumeric($(this)[0],AutoNumeric.getPredefinedOptions().numericPos.dotDecimalCharCommaSeparator);
 });`
```

So now I need to figure out why the decimal is not working for my fourth input

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve exactly?

If you want to have 'basic' input with the usual comma as the digit group separator and the dot as the decimal point, then just use:

```
new AutoNumeric.multiple('#form1 input');
```

On the other hand, if you only want positive values, use:

```
new AutoNumeric.multiple('#form1 input', { minimumValue : 0 });
```

Lastly you were mentioning currency; I would suggest using on the the predefined currency format, and if you do not find yours then 1) ask for it to be included in the AutoNumeric library using the github issues, and 2) just configure it as you wish, for instance like:

```
new AutoNumeric.multiple('#form1 input', { currencySymbol : '€' });
```

Do note that you can *fiddle* with the options pretty easily using the official [autoNumeric configurator](http://autonumeric.org/configurator).